# difference between environment namespace:ggplot2 and package:ggplot2

Tags: r, package, namespaces

when I run the following code:

```
pryr::parenvs(ggplot, TRUE)
```

I got the following result:

label                             name
1  <environment: namespace:ggplot2>  ""
2  <environment: 0x000001ecc58339e0> "imports:ggplot2"
3  <environment: namespace:base>     ""
4  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>        ""
5  <environment: package:testthat>   "package:testthat"
6  <environment: package:devtools>   "package:devtools"
7  <environment: package:usethis>    "package:usethis"
8  <environment: package:ggplot2>    "package:ggplot2"
9  <environment: package:pryr>       "package:pryr"
10 <environment: 0x000001ecc63f3d88> "tools:rstudio"
11 <environment: package:stats>      "package:stats"
12 <environment: package:graphics>   "package:graphics"
13 <environment: package:grDevices>  "package:grDevices"
14 <environment: package:utils>      "package:utils"
15 <environment: package:datasets>   "package:datasets"
16 <environment: package:methods>    "package:methods"
17 <environment: 0x000001ecc3d1a978> "Autoloads"
18 <environment: base>               ""
19 <environment: R_EmptyEnv>         ""

I see ggplot2 shows up two times, one in namespace and the other in package

what is the difference?

Comment: I gather this is `parenvs` from the *pryr* package?

Comment: Yes,it is from pryr

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself and post it here:[answer source link](https://r-pkgs.org/dependencies-mindset-background.html#:%7E:text=The%20package%20environment%20controls%20how,the%20function%20finds%20its%20variables.)

Every namespace environment has the same set of ancestors, as depicted in Figure 11.4:
[image]

Each namespace has an imports environment that can contain bindings to functions used by the package that are defined in another package. The imports environment is controlled by the package developer with the NAMESPACE file. Specifically, directives such as importFrom() and imports() populate this environment.

Explicitly importing every base function would be tiresome, so the parent of the imports environment is the base namespace. The base namespace contains the same bindings as the base environment, but it has a different parent.

The parent of the base namespace is the global environment. This means that if a binding isn’t defined in the imports environment the package will look for it in the usual way. This is usually a bad idea (because it makes code depend on other loaded packages), so R CMD check automatically warns about such code. It is needed primarily for historical reasons, particularly due to how S3 method dispatch works.

**Important thing is namespace env include all functions the author defined in a package while package env only include the functions the author wants you to see**

Comment: The namespace includes all objects (incl functions) that are defined in the package. The package env contains those that are exported, + the data contained in `getNamespaceInfo(ns, "lazydata")` (e.g.`dplyr::band_members`) vs  + the imports that the package reexports (e.g. `%>%` in dplyr)